# How to submit a form using the exact url using two dots in grails form?

Tags: forms, grails

I having a form like

```
<g:form url="../sodaProduct/addProduct">
      //
</g:form>
```

if I submit this form, the request url is going like

```
http://localhost:8080/VendorMachine/sodaProduct/addProduct
```

But if I am using the form with that two dots means

The url is constructed like this

```
http://localhost:8080/VendorMachine/sodaProduct/sodaProduct/addProduct
```

Can someone explain, and what is right way to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your explanation, it appears that the first way is the most logical one. Remember that Grails is designed to follow the MVC framework, so you should be submitting a form to a controller. You can specify this by using the `controller` and `action` attributes.

```
<g:form controller="sodaProducts" action="addProduct">
    //
</g:form>
```

This will generate a URL for you, and will probably make your life easier. Plus, it makes it easier for the user to follow the flow of information from the view back to the controller. Remember that the whole point of Grails is that you're not bogged down in these sorts of details.

Comment: @Suganthan I don't see why this changes anything. You don't need the URL when submitting a form via javascript

Comment: You can call the `submit()` method on the `form` element that is generated by the `g:form` tag. Give your form a `name` attribute, and use that in your Javascript as the id.

Answer (score 0):

that was easy task to do ... as you have beinged expermernting you should also have dome expernmeting this way.

to get

```
http://localhost:8080/VendorMachine/sodaProduct/addProduct
```

use this one simply:

```
<g:form url="../addProduct">
      //
</g:form>
```

but this might create a problem .